# Delay per each thread in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

`DOWNLOAD_DELAY` parameter sets a delay per each downloaded page. But what I would like to have instead is a delay set per each scrapy thread. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: In order to not confuse the readers you should make clear what framework you are talking about before starting with special parameters.

Comment: Scrapy doesn't really use threads, so it's kinda unclear what you're asking. Could you elaborate on what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: @stranac if I have `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 16`, I want to have a delay after each 16 requests.

Comment: I see. I guess you could assign different `download_slot`s to your requests to achieve a similar result, but I don't see any benefit over simply having `1/16` the delay.